# FOSUserBundle - Event set variable in session when success authentication?

Tags: php, symfony, session, events, fosuserbundle

I would like to know if it is possible to insert a variable in the session if authentication succeds (using with FOSUserBundle).

It is more or less than two lines to insert.

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$this->$session->set('type','OneType');
```

Is there a very simple way to do it? I really want to do it when there is successful authentication, not anywhere.

Comment: Yes sorry, it was the end of my day, I'm French I do not know if there is a jet lag. I will look at your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the event `security.interactive_login`. ([Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-success-and-failure-events))

Simple example, using [an event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber):

```
<?php
// src/EventSubscriber/SecuritySubscriber.php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

class SecuritySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface  
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
         SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'successfulLogin',
        ];
    }

    public function successfulLogin( InteractiveLoginEvent $event )
    {
        $event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('foo', 'bar');
    }
}
```

You haven't specified version, but this should work on a default installation for Symfony 4.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, my symfony version is Symfony 3.4
So I will look for your answer and I will leave a feedback

EDIT: If I have two authentication methods ( locale and CAS), can I use this event just for the locale authentication ?

Comment: This should work for 3.4 as well. It would catch all authentication methods; but I can’t test right now (mobile). You could differentiate the method within the event subscriber.